# Bundling not reflecting changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I am working on the bundling feature for the first time. This is an MVC project.

All the script library references that are to be rendered in the body tag are bundled and they load fine.

I have included a new library in the bundle list. After deploying the new dll, I am expecting that the changes will reflect in the site on initial page load, but that did not happen and I had to do a hard refresh to see the change.

Is this normal.

If it was without bundling, I would add ?v=somenumber for css or js reference file so that it will reflect the changes without doing a hard refresh.

How do I achieve that with bundling. Does it automatically do that, because that did not happen in my case.

```
private void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrapcss").Include(
                "~/assets/css/bootstrap.css"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                "~/assets/css/slider-menu.jquery.css",
                "~/assets/css/lightgallery.css",
                "~/assets/css/print.css"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scriptshead").Include(
                "~/assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
                ));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scriptsbody").Include(
                "~/assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js", //included this new one which only loaded after hard refresh
                "~/assets/js/jquery-ui.js",
                "~/assets/js/bootstrap.js"));

}
```

Comment: Did you compile in release mode?  Release mode should include the ?v=abc###

Comment: @Paritosh It's in release mode. I did not add any versions. Do I need to add version for every change even when bundling?

Comment: No i believe it's in release mode it will update that ?v= on it's own whenever you build it.